# Downloading a Tensorflow Dataset (MOVi) from GCS

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to download the MOVi datasets that are implemented by Kubric (https://github.com/google-research/kubric/tree/main/challenges/movi) to disk.
According to the documentation of Kubric, we can access the data simply via

```py
ds, info = tfds.load("movi_b", data_dir="gs://kubric-public/tfds", with_info=True)
```

This works, but it appears that the data is being streamed from GCS, instead of being downloaded. It seems from the tfds documentation that it should be very straight-forward to download the dataset, but that's not the case. I tried to follow the documentation of `tfds.load` (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load):

- I tried passing `download=True`
- I tried passing `download=True`, together with `download_and_prepare_kwargs={"download_dir": "data"}`
- I tried `try_gcs=False`
- I tried setting the environment variable `TFDS_DATA_DIR`
- I tried calling `ds["train"].save("data")`. This actually downloads the data, but it will quickly fill up 32GB of memory, then crash. I tried looking into sharding, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem and the documentation doesn't help much.

I am using `tensorflow_datasets==4.7.0`.

Neither the `tensorflow_datasets`, nor the Kubric repos seem to actively review issues, so I'm out of ideas. How can I actually download this dataset to disk?

Answer (score 0):

"movi_b" isn't a dataset provided by tensorflow_datasets.
They're assuming that you've imported the `movi_b.py` file in that directory
Importing the file registers the dataset.

So in a notebook I ran:

```
# get the movi_b.py file 
!curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google-research/kubric/main/challenges/movi/movi_b.py

#install pypng
!pip install pypng

# register the datasaet
import movi_b

# data_dir is where to download to.
ds, info = tfds.load("movi_b", data_dir="./dataset/downloads", with_info=True)
```

That should work. But the code in the file is broken.

I can't find a version of tfds that can run that code. In the newest tfds some `tfds.core.ReadWritePath` annotations fail. If you delete those it fails because `gs://research-brain-kubric-xgcp/jobs/movi_b_regen_10k`.

Can you report this bug on the repo?

So it you want a local copy, tfds will not work.

But the `gs://kubric-public/tfds` bucket is public access.

You can list files:

```
gsutil ls gs://kubric-public/tfds
```

```
gs://kubric-public/tfds/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/kubric_frames/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_a/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_b/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_c/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_d/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_e/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_f/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/msn_easy_frames/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/multi_shapenet_frames/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/nerf_synthetic_frames/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/nerf_synthetic_scenes/
gs://kubric-public/tfds/shapenet_pretraining/
```

And you can download them with:

```
mkdir tfds/
gsutil -m cp -r gs://kubric-public/tfds/movi_b tfds/movi_b
```

Note that it's 260GB.

Once that's done I think this should work:

```
ds, info = tfds.load("movi_b", data_dir="tfds/", with_info=True)
```

What a mess!